# Get related data without relationship between tables

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.1

When I have two models with one to many relationship, they look like the models below:

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int StudentID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ClassID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ClassID")]
    public virtual Class Class { get; set; }
}

public class Class
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ClassID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

This means that I can use the include method to get the related data. Now I work on a project with more than 600 tables. For these tables there are no relationships and I can not create relationships between the tables. Is there a way to link the models somehow so that I will be able to get the related data?

Comment: Relationships in the entity model are the links. Usually they have corresponding relationships in the database, but that's not mandatory (although you might get unexpected results if the dependent data contains FKs with no corresponding PK in the related table because EF Core assumes relationships are enforced in the database). Another way is not to try linking them at model level and use plain LINQ join queries.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can join tables without Relationships in Model Classes.

For example assume you have `TeacherId` in both of your tables `Student` and `Class`

You can join two tables based on `TeacherId` as follows

```
DbContext.Students
.Join(DbContext.Classes,student=>student.TeacherId,class=>class.TeacherId, (std,tchr)=> new {std,tchr});
```